# I need to create a MyIsam table that has an iniital autoincrement value of 0

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am using mysql 5.7.18.
I tried:

```
  CREATE TABLE t1 (
    `UID` int(10) auto_increment,
    day  int(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (`UID`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

When i looked at the table info in workbench, it shows the autoinc value is 1.
The weird thing is that I managed to set it to 0 in two other tables!
I also tried:

`alter table t1 auto_increment=0;`

I did this before any data was written into the table.
I'm at a bit of a loss.
Any recommendations?

Update:

```
 CREATE TABLE `sname`.`z` (
  `Uid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Uid`))
  ENGINE = MyISAM
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

This creates the table with the autoincrement start at 0
I do not understand why the top example does not* do what I want it to and the bottom one does.

Comment: what mean auto_increment =  0 ?

Comment: At the risk of being condescending: MySql permits the initial value of an auto increment field to be set at table creation time.  It also permits you to change the next autoincrement value to be changed - as long as its greater than the values that have already been used.     if you dont specify the value of the autoincrement field at table creation time - mysql sets it to 1.  Perfectly reasonable and about what you would expect.  in my case (and i admit its a bit pathological)  I need it to start at 0 so when I import a bunch of data that uses a starting index of 0 things line up properly.

Comment: i don't set auto_increment to 0  in at creation time but when import data the value are inserted correctly with the first istance equal to 1 and so one ..

Comment: That is the behavior I would expect.Having said that, I need the first record that i insert to have a uid of 0, not one.

Comment: so try  .. in my case  i have a correct behavior without set:auto_increment to 0

Comment: You are communicating to me that you are able to create the table and have the first value as 1.  The question states I need to to be set to 0.  The update says that I have found out how to do that, but I do not under stand why the second form of the create table gives me the result I am after.

Answer (score 0):

After even more research, it would appear that you cannot have 0 for an initial value in an autoincrement field.